# What files on Android phone allow remote access to the device?

Tags: applications, remote-access

I was wondering what files/apps on Android phone allow remote access to the device.  For instance I had a problem with my phone and had to speak with my provider and they asked permission to access the phone remotley.  Which files/programs allow for that type of access?

Comment: Please explain "remote access". There's no universal remote access method available on Android devices except ADB.

Comment: Is your phone a generic Android phone or is it branded by your mobile network operator? What device model is your phone and have you notice something while your provider was connected remotely?

Comment: Well when this happened it was an LG v10 I believe.  However now I have a Samsung, but all Android devices can be accessed remotely by the carrier correct?

Comment: All Android devices aren't sold by carriers. You can buy an Android device which is not bound to any network. And providing remote access to carrier is not a universal phenomenon AFAIK.